# using Autofac in Factory method

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, factories

I am bit confused I have a snippet on domainevents where `

```
public class StructureMapDomainEventHandlerFactory : IDomainEventHandlerFactory
{
    public IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler<T>> GetDomainEventHandlersFor<T>
                                           (T domainEvent) where T : IDomainEvent
        return ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IDomainEventHandler<T>>();
}
```

where StructureMap is exploited. I just embarked on DI using Autofac how this supposed to be implemented in Autofac. Since there is no notion of Static Class.

In general is this approach correct ? what is the point of using DI within the Factory class would not be nice to refer it directly  somewhere else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular example is actually provided for you OOB. Just take a dependency on `IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler<>>` and Autofac will serve the collection to you:

```
public class ClientClass
{
     public ClientClass(IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler<OfSomeType>> eventHandlers)
     {
     }
}
```

**Update**: here's an example of a factory class that could include some logic around resolving services from a container:

```
public class AutofacDomainEventHandlerFactory : IDomainEventHandlerFactory
{
    private readonly IComponentContext _context;
    public AutofacDomainEventHandlerFactory(IComponentContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler<T>> GetDomainEventHandlersFor<T>
                                           (T domainEvent) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        return _context.Resolve<IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler<T>>>();
    }
}
```

That said, I encourage you to explore the possibilities of using [strongly-typed metadata in Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Metadata). By "tagging" services with metadata, factory classes can do extensive logic only by examining the metadata and thus have as little as possible dependency on the actual framework used.

**Update 2**: thanks to @Nicholas, here's an excellent [sample approach to domain events using Autofac](https://github.com/readify/iocdevday). The class that propagate events to handlers can be found [here](https://github.com/Readify/IocDevDay/blob/master/TinySheets/Eventing/AutofacDomainEventDispatcher.cs).

Comment: ok thanks. however what is the correlation of factory class to di frameworks.how we should use it in combination.had perused some materials on delegate factories in autofac, but what if logic is complicated.

Comment: IMO, factory classes is somewhere in-between DI and business logic. Sometimes we need specific logic around our resolves. These factories will certainly be bound to the framework (as your StructureMap sample shows), no different with Autofac. I'll update my sample to show how a **factory class** can be made to interact with the container.

Comment: There's a complete/executable sample showing domain events with Autofac here: https://github.com/readify/iocdevday. Specific class fulfilling this role is https://github.com/Readify/IocDevDay/blob/master/TinySheets/Eventing/AutofacDomainEventDispatcher.cs.

Comment: Ah, very nice and clean sample app! Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Nicholas,  I had loved the way you coded the  iocdevday example. Please do not mind my frequent questions, however is there any source where I can refer where it directs to  guides to the approach you have taken as building ddd domain events. thank you